# U-Boot: Influence which kernel image to load in SPL

Tags: kernel, spl, u-boot

In U-Boot (from Denx), is there a possibility to influence in the SPL part what uImage file gets loaded from the U-Boot part?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Not much information you have provided, so I can't tell exactly how, but I'll give you an example what could be done on am335x board using NAND disk that stores multiple images.

1) Find boot scripts your board is using. Usually they are located in *./configs/yourboardname.h* The lines of interest should look something like:

```
    #define CONFIG_EXTRA_ENV_SETTINGS \
<..>
    "nandsrcaddr=0x280000\0" \
    "nandimgsize=0x500000\0" \
    "nandboot=echo Booting from nand ...; " \
        "run nandargs; " \
        "nand read ${loadaddr} ${nandsrcaddr} ${nandimgsize}; " \
        "bootm ${loadaddr}\0" \
<...>
```

...that translates to "copy a kernel image from `nandsrcaddr` location on NAND to ram and try to run it from there".

2) Since environmental variables are stored on NAND in a static location, you can easily write a simple function in SPL that manually overwrites `nandsrcaddr` using it's address (I'm not going into details how to find out that address, again, it depends on your configuration). After that, recalculate CRC and write it too. See the structure of environmentals - `struct environment_s`.

3) Add a switch to SPL `board_init_r` function (*./common/spl/spl.c*) so when a certain condition is met (button press during boot, jumper settings etc.) your function (see 2) is called and the address of a kernel image is changed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will dig into this approach and figure out how to rite this function. I am working with an omap4430/60 platform. I already found the header file correspnding to my platform (include(configs/omap4_common.h). However, I did not know how to dynamically redefine these arguments. As far as I know, my platform does not have a NAND memory.

Comment: @PeterRussel, NAND is not necessary, I took it only as an example. What you need to do is to pass pointer/flag etc. from SPL to U-Boot. You still boot system from some media, and if it's non read-only, this task becomes trivial.